# How do I edit HTML.tmLanguage in sublime on mac osx

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I'm to change it to support non-quote id, as in:

`<div id=someId></div>`

I found this
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8129

But am having issues finding where to edit the tmLanguage file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't listen to Jamie's answer.  You should never be editing the Pristine packages.  Instead, you can find all of Sublime Text's packages and grammar files in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages` or, from within Sublime Text, go to `Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages`.  However, if you edit HTML.tmLanguage from within the HTML folder, your changes will be overridden when Sublime Text is updated.  To prevent this, duplicate the HTML folder and renaming it to Better HTML.  Then in your User Settings (`Preferences > Settings - User`) add the following:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "HTML",
    "Vintage"
],
```

By ignoring the default HTML package, Sublime Text will be forced to use your version of the HTML.tmLanguage file and your changes will be preserved.

Comment: Kinda catch-22... This time you'd miss updates on the original HTML package. If only there was a documented way to edit/customize it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the HTML.tmLanguage file by going to `/Applications` and then control/right click on `Sublime Text 2.app` and select 'Show Package Contents'. Then navigate to `/Contents/Mac OS/Pristine Packages/`.

Inside that folder, you should see a collection of sublime-package files. Find `HTML.sublime-package` and rename it to `HTML.zip`. You should then be able to extract the archive, just like any other zip folder, and inside you should find all assests related to Sublime's HTML package - including the HTML.tmlanguage.

Make sure to recompress and then rename the folder back to .sublime-package after making your edits!

***EDIT:*** I have since recognised that this is incorrect, the Pristine Packages should never be edited. Follow BoundinCode's answer instead!